# Can't access https version of WAMP site outside localhost

Tags: apache, ssl, wamp

After setting up SSL on my 64-bit WAMP server on Windows 7, I tried to access the `https` version of the site. However, I get this error: `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

[image]

I've port forwarded, shut down my firewall, and made sure my certificate and key is valid (bought from a verified CA). Even if they weren't, Chrome would still provide a warning asking me if it's okay to proceed. Accessing the `http` version of the website works.

I tried accessing the same website from another computer on my network using its local IP and no luck. Same error. However, when I type `https://mypublicdomain.com` on the same PC I'm hosting the site from, it loads fine without any warnings from Chrome, says "Connection is secure." Same thing with `https://localhost`, it just warns me before visiting the website.

I've tried making a new `<VirtualHost *:443>` block in `httpd-vhosts.conf` with `Require all granted`, however it still seems to give the error on remote PCs trying to access the site on or off my network from my domain.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Apache version `2.4.23`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just figured it out. I had another `<VirtualHost ...>` block configured to the 443 port in my `httpd-vhosts.conf` that was causing the 443 port to not run under SSL at all becasue it did not have `SSLEngine on` in it. After deleting that block in that file, just leaving the port 80 one, it seems to be working. I also had to make sure that `NameVirtualHost *:443` was directly above `<VirtualHost _default_:443>` in my `httpd-ssl.conf` file or else the whole setup would not work.